# Twitter bootstrap tabs not appearing

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I've been having some difficulties trying to get the tabs to work in the twitter bootstrap, and have been slightly confused on what the documentation is trying to say.  I have a small page that has three tabs. I have the first tab appearing, but I can't seem to switch between the other two.

According to the [Twitter Bootstrap Documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs) I need to activate each tab, which I have done with one of them

```
 $('#tabBar a[href="#Sewer"]').tab('show');
```

But whenever I try to click on the tab, it doesn't seem to switch to that tab.  Here is the fiddle of what I've got so far: [Tab Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbredlow/LBWHJ/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery is required for bootstrap plugins to work
Include jQuery to your page using

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LBWHJ/1/)

Comment: Wow, I can't believe it was something that simple. Thanks for that.